# JSON error in Chrome and IE only : Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am trying to get some data via ajax but for some reason it gives errors in the console in Chrome and IE only.  It works fine in Firefox.

Here is my code:

**PHP**

```
function get_data() {
     $data = array( 'value' => '50', 'type' => 'box' );
     echo json_encode($data);
     exit;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".click").click(function() {
     var data = {
      action: "get_data"
     };

     $.post( "http://domain.com/", data, function(response) {
          var newResponse = $.parseJSON(response);
          console.log(newResponse);
     }); 
});
```

So this code works fine in Firefox but for some reason it doesn't work in Chrome and IE...In Chrome, it doesn't even get to the console.log function before it errors out.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Can you post what your AJAX response contains? Perhaps there's something invalid being output by your PHP that is causing issues with the other browsers but FF is more forgiving of.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in Chrome in the first line of the callback function in $.post and you will see what's wrong.

Comment: If you comment out the two lines in your `$.post` callback, does the error go away?  I'm wondering if it's coming from the `$.parseJSON`.

Comment: The errant answer was deleted, but I just wanted to point out that Javascript does not require semicolons as line terminators. They are optional.

Comment: The response is correct {"value":"50","type":"box"} in firefox...and yes the error goes away if I comment out the parseJSON line...

Comment: Not too sure how to set breakpoints...:(

Comment: what is the error text? Also try to use your responce without parseJSON, e.g. response.value or response.type

Comment: Without parseJSON, it would return undefined...The error that comes back from Chrome is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.js:2
e.extend.parseJSON jquery.js:2
(anonymous function) scripts.js:60
f.Callbacks.o jquery.js:2
f.Callbacks.p.fireWith jquery.js:2
w jquery.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d

Comment: Can you try this sample: http://fiddle.jshell.net/TWNWH/ does it work for you?

Comment: that means something wrong either with your string, either with jquery file: try to copy-paste code from example into your function, just to make sure that .parseJSON is working fine. however I guess that you already have parsed object and you are trying to parse it again, try this now: http://fiddle.jshell.net/TWNWH/1/ is it the same error?

Comment: no, this doesn't give the same error. your sample gives cannot read property error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17423/discussion-between-felix-and-rick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after hours and hours of trying to figure out what is wrong, I finally figured out that there was an issue with a redirect of some sort on the ajax url.  Not sure how that redirect got there but once I removed it, everything started to work.  And by the way, it was not effecting Firefox is only because I was logged in to the site.  I guess the redirect had some kind of check if a person is logged in, don't redirect the ajax url.

But in any case, I just like to share that in case someone else has the same issue as me where the code is correct and still not working.

And I like to just mention a big thanks to Felix for going out of his way to try and help me.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should work without .parseJSON. Just like this, at least it works for me:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url...",
    type: "post",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.Result) {
            data.value1;
            data.value2;
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    }
});
```

data is just my type like { value1:'123', value2: '345', Result: true}

Answer (score 0):

Which version of jQuery are you using? Older versions are less forgiving about whitespace in JSON files that are returned

Comment: I believe the version is 1.7.2...can you please elaborate more on the white space?  How is white space introduced if its created in PHP via array?